# youtube-dl : Downloading a youtube user's complete video collection

Tags: video, download, youtube, youtube-dl

Previously, whenever I had to download a user's complete videos, I'd just use something like:

```
youtube-dl -ciw ytuser:LinusTechTips
```

But now this does not seem to work anymore. When I issue this command, it starts downloading another video which says that the youtube device support has changed.

So, it seems like some changes have happened from the youtube side and youtube-dl hasn't adapted to that. Downloading single videos and playlists work just fine. But downloading a user's complete videos isn't working anymore.

Is their any workaround? Does anyone know of any changes in the youtube-dl syntax which might make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in the latest release of `youtube-dl`. To install the latest release, you should use `pip` to update it as your package manager might not be providing the latest updated release. To update it using `pip`, use this command:

```
sudo pip install -U youtube-dl
```

After the update, everything works normal. I got this info after filing a bug-report here: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/5785

More instructions on installing/updating using `pip` are here: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl